# Javascript Class loses reference to 'this' (using babel)

Tags: javascript, class, google-chrome, babeljs

```
class UrlProvider {
    constructor(root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    getUrl() {
        return this.root + "/api/Situations";
    }
} 


class Repository {
    constructor(urlProvider) {
        this.urlProvider = urlProvider;
    }

    getAsync() {
        var self = this;
        return httpGetAsync(self.urlProvider.getUrl()).then(function(d) {
            return d.map(x => new Situation(x));
        });
    }
}



class PromiseCacher {
    constructor(cache, promise) {
        var self = this;
        self.cache = cache;
        self.promise = promise;
    }
    runAsync() {
        var self = this;

        return self.promise().then(function (d) {
            self.cache.set(d);
            return d;
        });
    }
}

var urlProvider = new UrlProvider(appsettings.url);
var repository = new Repository(urlProvider);
var cache = new Cache();

var promiseCacher = new PromiseCacher(cache, repository.getAsync);

promiseCacher.runAsync()
```

When debugging the above code, chrome will crash inside the getAsync function of the repository because self.urlProvider is undefined. 
Inside the repository getAsync function 'this' is referring to the instance of PromiseCacher which is what actually calls it.

What's going on?

Re-writing

```
var promiseCacher = new PromiseCacher(cache, ()=> repository.getAsync());
```

makes it work as I would expect.

Comment: The class doesn't *lose* a reference to `this` - it never has such a reference in the first place. The value of `this` (for ordinary, non-arrow functions) is determined solely by how the function is *called*, not where it's defined.

Comment: And your arrow function solution is a fine one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because first of all `repository.getAsync` is not a promise. Instead it is a function. By storing the reference of `repository.getAsync` to a different object property you "alter" its `this` value. Take a look at the following example:

```
var obj = {
    a: 42,
    func: function(){
        return this.a;
    }
};

obj.func();  // 42

var b = obj.func;
b();         // undefined
```

The example is comparable to your code:

```
class Repository{
    // urlProvider = ...
    getAsync (){ /* ... */ }
}

var repo = new Repository(/* ... */);
repo.getAsync();  // works

var cacher = new PromiseCacher(/* ... */);
cacher.promise = repo.getAsync;
cacher.promise();  // does not work
```